# Jquery Negation

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-online

I am trying to hide items from an unordered list. This code works for some sites under SharePoint, but not for others.

On sites where it works, it has 4 items under the `ul` and in sites where it's not working has 3 items under the `ul`.

```js
public componentDidMount() {
  var endpointUrl = this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/?$expand=groups";

  $.ajax({
    url: endpointUrl,
    method: "GET",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var allowedgroups = ["Checking_External_User"];
      var userGroups = data.d.Groups.results;
      var foundGroups = userGroups.filter(function(g) {
        return allowedgroups.indexOf(g.LoginName) > -1;
      });
      if (foundGroups.length == 0) {
        $("#linkUL li:not(:first)").hide();
      }
    },
  });
```

Html:

```
<div class="subsite-wrapper"><h3 class="subsite-title">Site Links</h3><ul id="linkUL" class="subsite-link-list full-width-link">
<li><a target="_blank" data-interception="off" href="">
<i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span id="gotoDefaultPage">Quarry Services Handbook</span></a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="" data-interception="off">
<i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>Miscellaneous</span></a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="" data-interception="off">
<i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>Forms</span></a></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML with this code and the `data` you get from the request -- the version that *doesn't* work -- so we can reproduce the problem. The editor toolbar offers a way to create a runnable snippet: this would be the best for you to do now.

Comment: The behaviour would imply that the data returned from the AJAX request is different between the sites. This would mean it's not a JS/client side problem, but a server side one.

Comment: Also, remove `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice.

Comment: @trincot i have added the html part.

Comment: Please provide the `data` you get from the request so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am sorry, @trincot, I am all new to this stuff.
what data exactly you are referring to?

Comment: In the `success` callback, you get a `data` argument. Can you output it as JSON, like with `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` and provide us that? Of course, it should be the data for which the problem occurs. I suppose you already looked at that data yourself while debugging...